# @SecondaryTable causes internal server error

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, named-query

I have two tables named User and Role(POJO classes). I am using hibernate and named query to access data from postgresql. User has *roleid* which is the foreign key referencing *id* in Role table.

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.logincheck",query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.loginName = :loginName AND u.password = :password")
```

If I am writing the above query to access contents of User table alone the code is working.

But I want to get one column from Role table so I add

```
@SecondaryTable(name="Role", 
pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", 
                                    referencedColumnName = "RoleID"))
```

When I add the above code I'm getting Internal sever error. I'm using tomcat 8.
How can I make it work and retrieve one column from the first query?

Comment: Lock at `cataluna.out` to see what is happend.

Comment: The trick is to read the error message, or to hire a medium. I'd go with the first solution.